# Why does padding lead to jumpy animation?

Tags: html, css

Why does the `::before` pseudo element jump during a height transition when I apply top and bottom padding to its parent?

```css
a {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  /* Removing this padding resolves the animation issue, but why? */
  padding: 1em;
}

a::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0.06em;
  height: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  left: 0;
  transition: height 0.25s linear;
}

a:hover::before {
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.container {
  background: #3a3a3a;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 1em;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Hover Me</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have padding on an element, then apply position absolute on one of it's children the padding amount will be added as an offset to that child element.

Say you have `padding-top:10px;`, it'll become `top:10px`, i think some browsers do rest this.

## DEMO

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.test>div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.test:hover>div {
  position: absolute;
  /* uncomment this line to see it */
  /* top: 0; */
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

---

Now to fix your issue.

```css
a {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
}

a::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0.06em;
  height: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  left: 0;
  /* rest the top here */
  top: 0;
  transition: height 0.25s linear;
}

a:hover::before {
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  /* unsetting the top because top:0 bottom:0; is full heiht which will prevent the animation the way you want it*/
  /* unsetting the top and not the bottom so it goes upward */
  top: unset;
}

.container {
  background: #3a3a3a;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 1em;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Hover Me</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `bottom: 0` rule from `a:hover::before` to the `a::before` rule set.

In general, try to minimize amount of rules in selectors like `:hover` -- whenever a "hover" rule set applies, the chances of things jumping or moving because of inability to mentally calculate how the layout engine will render things, is ever higher the more properties are overriden. You don't need `bottom: 0` there, but if you need to align to the bottom, set it on the same rule set without the `:hover` to it, i.e. the `a::before` -- *it will be inherited anyway* by the element in the "hover" state. If you on the other hand only desire the height of an element to transition as you hover over, then that's the only rule that should be set there, should it not?

Comment: I like the advice of minimizing `:hover` rules and the like. However, in this case I am intentionally changing the anchor point to get the desired animation.

Comment: Am I to understand you want your white line to spread out from the vertical center of the following block?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your before content is not aligned properly.
Here is the solution...

```css
a {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  /* Removing this padding resolves the animation issue, but why? */
  padding: 1em;
}

a::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0.06em;
  height: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  transition: height 0.25s linear;
}

a:hover::before {
  top:0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  background: #3a3a3a;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 1em;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Hover Me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Jeet! That does indeed make the animation not jump, but I would like it to grow upwards and then shrink upwards as in my example. :-)

Comment: This was the animation I created first. But I am trying to do the reverse animation: Grow and shrink upwards, not grow and shrink downwards. Also, I am trying to learn why it happens more so than fixing it.

Comment: This is happening because when you remove top:0; from a::before content, the absolute position doesn't let is align. check developer tool with hover position on to see where it is aligned.